# Mockito Stubbed Spy sometimes calls and sometimes does not call the spied object methods

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito

***QUESTION***

In a `@Test`, how can I achieve both;

1. Call a real method from a Kotlin class under test and
2. stub the inner calls it does to other methods within such class under test.

***SCENARIO***

I am using the following libraries;

```
testCompile "com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:1.5.0"
testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.12.0"
```

I also have a simple kotlin class in the form of

```
class MyClass() {

    fun parentFunc() {
        funA()
    }

    fun funA() {
        //DOES SOMETHING WHICH I ASSUME IS IRRELEVANT FOR ANSWERING THE QUESTION
    }
}
```

***TESTING WITH A SPY***

```
@Test
fun myTest() {
    val myClassSpy = spy(MyClass())
    Mockito.doNothing().`when`(myClassSpy.funA())
    //Mockito.doNothing().whenever(myClassSpy.funA()) also throws the same error

    myClassSpy.parentFunc()

    verify(myClassSpy, times(1)).funA()
}
```

Which throws the error,

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.MockitoKt.doNothing(Mockito.kt:108)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, which is not supported
 3: you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction if completed
```

Another Test case;

```
@Test
fun myTest() {
    val myClassSpy = Mockito.spy(MyClass())

    myClassSpy.parentFunc()

    verify(myClassSpy, times(1)).funA()
}
```

gives the following error:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
myClass.funA();

However, there was exactly 1 interaction with this mock:
myClass.parentFunc();
```

Also, anytime I attempt to use the debugger to call myClassSpy methods or something related to it, it throws the following error:

```
com.sun.jdi.InternalException : Unexpected JDWP Error: 41
```

[image]

I have attempted to use

```
Mockito.`when`(myClassSpy.funA()).then { }
Mockito.`when`(myClassSpy.funA()).thenAnswer { }
Mockito.`when`(myClassSpy.funA()).thenReturn(Unit)
```

***TESTING WITH A MOCK***

Mocking the whole class does not work in this case because it is a mock and does not call the real method under test:

```
@Test
fun myTest() {
    val myMock: MyClass = mock()

    myMock.parentFunc()

    verify(myMock, times(1)).funA()
}
```

Same error:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
myClass.funA();

However, there was exactly 1 interaction with this mock:
myClass.parentFunc();
```

If I further call the real method it also shows the same `wanted but not invoked myClass.funA();` error:

```
@Test
fun myTest() {
    val myMock: MyClass = mock()

    Mockito.`when`(myMock.parentFunc()).thenCallRealMethod()

    myMock.parentFunc()

    verify(myMock, times(1)).funA()
}
```

I also, tried opening `MyClass`but threw the same errors.

Thus, how can I stub methods from a spy so that when I test methods from such spied object it does not propagate the call to other methods which I do not want to further mock.

*Any help, suggestion, idea... in order to test these type of methods is highly appreciated.*

Comment: When testing with spy, `when` method must get the spied object rather than its method as argument. Should you call `Mockito.doNothing().when(myClassSpy).funA()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

- When the code base is all in **Kotlin** the solution was:

  Use [MockK](https://mockk.io/) which is a library for testing and mocking Kotlin Code.
- When the code base is written in **both Java and Kotlin** the solution was:

  Use [MockK](https://mockk.io/) for testing & mocking Kotlin and [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/) for testing & mocking Java code.

Answer (score 0):

for me mocking kotlin classes with mockito sometimes works and sometimes it does not, so what i usually do is extract an for that class, and that always works.

also mocks are for testing interactions so you should not mock a method on the same class that you are testing but a different class that you pass to the constructor (dependency injection) then you can inject a mock at test time and the correct dependency at production time.

```
class MyTestedClass(val funManager:MyUsedClass) {    
    fun parentFunc() {
        funManager.funA()
    }
}
```